# Tomcat 7 giving HTTP 405 when calling static page

Tags: tomcat

I created one dynamic project using eclipse IDE. I added one html page Welcome.html inside the WebContent folder in project CollegeManagement. I deployed the project on Apache Tomcat-7.0.47. After the deployment, I can see one folder CollegeManagement inside the C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps which contain Welcome.html. When I am running the application by right clicking Welcome.html and selecting Run on server, it's giving the error HTTP 405. Can anybody please help me in resolving this issue? Please find the snapshot here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/843/3q0r.png/

Project structure image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/826/ufep.png/

HTML page Welcome.html contain

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8181/CollegeManagement/do">
Operation<input type="text" name="op"/>
<button type="submit">Do</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml contain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CollegeManagement</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
   <!--  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file> -->
     <welcome-file></welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.vijay.Welcome</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
</web-app>
```

I am trying to access static page on the server and it should return without checking web.xml or the contents of HTML file. Why is it returning GET method is not supported?

FYI: I've tried by renaming the Welcome.html to College.html, issue still persist.

Many Thanks.

Comment: can you share you eclipse web project structure.

Comment: Please post your code to find exact problem ...

Comment: here is the project structure image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/826/ufep.png/

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8181/CollegeManagement/do">
Operation<input type="text" name="op"/>
<button type="submit">Do</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Content of web.xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CollegeManagement</display-name>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.vijay.Welcome</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
</web-app>

Answer (score 0):

Note : First check whether is there any incorrect url-pattern.

Use the following to ensure the default servlet container.

```
  <!-- Disables Servlet Container welcome file handling. Needed for compatibility with Servlet 3.0 and Tomcat 7.0 -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file></welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

It's because you may be calling doGet() without actually implementing doGet(). It's the default implementation of doGet() that throws the error saying the method is not supported.

Comment: I am calling static page and server should return it.

Comment: After commenting out the welcome-file-list inside web.xml, it is still giving the same problem. The point is calling to static page should not go through the web.xml. Server should return without checking any setting inside web.xml. Please correct me if I am wrong.